# use .Replace() to fix incorrect inline css

Tags: c#, css

I have this method that parses my rich text to HTML. I noticed that is some places it is composing the inline style like this:

```
<DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;">
```

notice the font-size is missing the 'pt' at the end, which is breaking the report when I export to pdf.

Here is my code to handle it:

```
public static string RtfToHtml(string rtfText)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtfText)) return rtfText;
        if (!rtfText.Contains(@"{\rtf1")) return rtfText.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\r", "<br>");

        Converter converter = new Converter();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(converter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtfText));
        sb.Replace("font-size:12;", "font-size:12pt;");

        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());
            RemoveStyleTags(doc, "ol");
            RemoveStyleTags(doc, "ul");
            RemoveStyleTags(doc, "li");
            return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
        catch { }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

My question is this: Is there a more elegant way to perform the .Replace() method rather that doing this:

```
sb.Replace("font-size:12;", "font-size:12pt;");
sb.Replace("font-size:13;", "font-size:13pt;");
sb.Replace("font-size:14;", "font-size:14pt;");
...
sb.Replace("font-size:10000;", "font-size:10000pt;");
```

Obviously what I am trying to do is find all the mistyped font-size declaration, append the pt, while keeping the integer size they already have.

Comment: One of the few times I think I would recommend [Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) for pattern finding and replacing.

Comment: What is the reason you can't fix the root problem instead?

Comment: I wanted to look at the root problem, but couldn't seem to find where it was located. The developer who rolled this out is on vacation, so when he gets back I will ask him about it. I just got a little lost when trying to follow the code back, so I figured i would just intercept the string due to time and skill restraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx), like so:

```
public static string RtfToHtml(string rtfText)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtfText)) return rtfText;
    if (!rtfText.Contains(@"{\rtf1")) return rtfText.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\r", "<br>");

    Converter converter = new Converter();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(converter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtfText));
    string html = Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(), @"font-size:(\d*(\.\d+)?);", @"font-size:$1pt;");
    try
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        RemoveStyleTags(doc, "ol");
        RemoveStyleTags(doc, "ul");
        RemoveStyleTags(doc, "li");
        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
    catch { }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, and it works, but I ran into another problem. some of the html is font-size: 13.333333333333. I am not great with regex, do you know how to account for all the decimal places and do the same thing/

Comment: Looks like you figured it out.  I'll update the above answer to include that change, although I'm going to use (\.\d+)? to allow any number of decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Using RegEx? Something like:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(font-size:\s?\d+)");
regex.Replace(yourHtml, "$1pt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a loop like this

```
for(int i=12; i < 1001; i++)
{    
    sb.Replace("font-size:"+i.ToString()+";", "font-size:" i.ToString()+ "pt;");    
}
```

Comment: you should have the loop go from 0 to 1000000 just incase.

Comment: Good call, I thought about doing this after I posted the question. Regex seems like a cleaner solution, however this would seem to accomplish more or less the same this. One this I don't know that this could do is account for numbers like 13.3333333 which sometimes show up in font-size.